# Grub2 and password

Tags: security, grub2

I have an user account to log into `grub`, this works.  Every time I boot the computer I am asked for my username and password to boot my operating system.

How can I set `grub` so it only requests the username and the password when I try to edit the boot loader?  For example, when I normally start my computer I can get straight into the operating system, but if I want to edit the loader to gain superuser; Then I am requested the credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow selecting a boot menu option (as-is, without editing it) without a username/password query when GRUB has password(s) configured, you'll need to add the `--unrestricted` option to its `menuentry` line in `grub.cfg`.

You probably already have `set superusers="your_username"` set in your `grub.cfg`.

Example from [GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Security), with non-relevant parts elided:

```
set superusers="root"
password_pbkdf2 root grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.biglongstring
password user1 insecure

menuentry "May be run by any user" --unrestricted {
    ... existing menu entry contents here ...
}

menuentry "Superusers only" --users "" {
    ... existing menu entry contents here ...
}

menuentry "May be run by user1 or a superuser" --users user1 {
    ... existing menu entry contents here ...
}
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the simplified GRUB configuration (the `/etc/default/grub` file + the `grub-mkconfig` command) cannot do this for you directly. At minimum, you might need to edit the scripts in `/etc/grub.d/` directory to add the `--unrestricted` option to the boot entries you wish to be available without entering a password.

Comment: I have a hard time finding what should I put in these "set root=" and "linux" fields for the `menuentry` blocks.  I tried checking my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but I'm too blind to find anything useful there.  Any tip?

Comment: In your existing menu entries, there should already be the equivalents of the `set root=` and `linux` lines, since they define which partition and kernel file you're about to boot. With modern GRUB, the `set root=` may actually be replaced by `search ... --set=root ...` lines, for detecting the filesystem by its ID rather than by hardware position. The point is just to describe how to add `--unrestricted` to the `menuentry` line (or `--users ...`, if you want a password-protected menu entry).

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot.  I added the `--unrestricted` flag to the `10_linux` file to automatically generate it for the menu entries in a similar way it was done [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords) to limit access to certain users.